# Is the Stack Overflow site offline?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Currently when I try to access the stackoverflow.com site I get the error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". I take it this means that there is an error on the Stack Overflow server. If this is true, is there an ETA when it will be back up?

Comment: I think the problem is in your end. Did you try restart your computer and router?

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Stack Overflow functions fine.

Comment: Just you I think: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is a DNS error. Are you using a special/custom DNS server by chance? Whatever your resolution source it - it's not properly resolving `stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Down for everyone or just me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/https://stackoverflow.com/) indicates that SO is working properly, so it's almost certainly an issue on your end.  Check that you don't have any router or browser issues with accessing the site.  A restart of your computer, your router, and a clearing of your cookies and temp files from your browser should help clear out any issues.

If the problem persists, and no other site has a similar issue, check to make sure the site isn't blocked by your computer or browser security settings, or by a firewall.

If it *still* isn't back up, and you're certain there are no other issues with your computer, then your computer may be possessed by a vindictive former SO user, in which case you should seek spiritual help that we sadly cannot provide.